# Dependency 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.1.1' not found

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka

I tried to install Kafka with IntelliJ (in windows), but IntelliJ don't import changes. 
I create a Maven project with java8.
I add Kafka dependency to `pom.xml`

```
<groupId>com.test.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>testKafka</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

but version stayed red and popup this message

```
Dependency 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.1.1' not found
```

I tried everything on google to make it work.
I tried with multiple version of kafka.
I tried also with eclipse.
Can anyone give me solution

Comment: You've got a firewall which is blocking requests to Maven Central.

Comment: Is this the only artifact you have had trouble with? May consider manually downloading this jar and then deploying it in your local Maven repo.

Comment: Hua where can i find maven repo?

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/maven/where-is-maven-local-repository/

Comment: I don't know if did it write but i didn't work this is what I did(
 1. download kafka jar file form this link https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.apache.kafka
2. add it to .m2/repository
3.refresh project.
)

Answer (score 2):

go to maven setting(ctrl+alt+s and find maven), need to check the overwriting box next to the settings.xml

Answer (score 1):

If Maven doesn't have access to the internet, you can download a jar - as you did - and install it manually to your local repository:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file>\kafka-clients.jar -DgroupId=org.apache-kafka
    -DartifactId=kafka-clients -Dversion=2.1.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

The link which you provided in your comment doesn't refer to `kafka-clients` ...

If you are looking for specific artifacts, I recommend https://search.maven.org .
You can search there by Maven coordinates, or class names, packages

**Update**
Make sure your proxy settings are correct. See `~/.m2/settings.xml` .

```xml
<settings>

    <proxies>
        <!--
            proxy | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the
            network. |
        -->
        <proxy>
            <id>optional</id>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <username></username>
            <password></password>
            <host>your.proxy.com</host>
            <port>8080</port> <!-- proxy-specific -->
            <nonProxyHosts>localhost</nonProxyHosts>
        </proxy>
    </proxies>
<settings>
```

Comment: it didn't work, when I have runned this command it said that I have to download plugins (maven-clean-plugin,  maven-install-plugin, ...). When i download these plugin and tried to install them loccaly I got another problems relating to download other things. 
in my pc there an administrator account so when I want to install something I need this account from my supervisor. Do you think that maybe the problem in the firewall ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maven doesn't need admin priviliges. The command `mvn install:install-file` doesn't need admin privileges. Did you insert proxy settings in Mavens `settings.xml`?